# Is there a more reliable/alternative function for eval();

Tags: php, eval

I'm very aware about the dangers of eval and how your website can get defaced but as i'm using eval for my private online PHP editor, I was thinking about making it publically viewable but i'm afraid my website can get defaced easily. Any alternatives to eval(); ?

Comment: Why are you using it in the first place?

Comment: `eval` executes arbitrary code. How is a hypothetical alternative method of executing arbitrary code going to be more secure? You could (and should) forgo `eval` for something less powerful, but it's impossible to say what that might be if you don't provide specific information.

Comment: php editor for myself @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: That tells us nothing.